# jwt Passport.authenticate is not working in route in Node api

Tags: node.js, authentication, token

I am creating a token at the time of user login. And I am using `jwt-simple` module.I am following [this](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/) tutorial. Here is my login code.

```
apiRoutes.put('/login', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, result){
       if(result){
        var token=jwt.encode(user,config.secret);

        return res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT'+ token});         
      }else{
        return res.json("Incorrect Email and Password")
      }
    })
  })
});
```

and I am authenticating user at the `/dashboard` route:

```
apiRoutes.get('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),function(req, res) {
      var token=getToken(req.headers);
      if(token){
        var decode=jwt.decode(token, config.secret);

        req.userId = decode.name;
        User.findOne({name:decode.name}, function(err, user){
          if(err){res.json(err)}
            if(!user){
              return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'Authentication Failed'})
            }else{
              res.json({success:true, msg:'Welcome in the Area' +user.name+'!'})
            }
        })
      }else{
        return res.status(403).send({success:false, msg:'No Token Found'})
      }

      });

     getToken = function (head) {
      if (head && head.authorization) { 
        var parted = head.authorization.split(' ');

        if (parted.length === 2) { 
          console.log(parted[1]);
          return parted[1];
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
```

When I am hitting `/dashboard` api in `postman` then output is only `unauthorized`. And when i remove `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),` then output is `{success:false, msg:'No Token Found'}`.
I googled it but didn't found any solution. 
Please help me... Please, help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: No one is here for help????????//

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(decode)`?

Comment: its `null`... after ` var token=getToken(req.headers);` I am printing token `console.log(token)` then output is `null`

Comment: Now in `postman`, when I add `bearer` in the starting like `"authorization":Bearer <token>` then its working good.

Comment: Well, first, check your `header`. Then, if the error still persists, can you show your `passport` authentication strategy?

Comment: Yeah I checked... In postman its working good... But when I am hitting api using Angular than its not working.

Comment: So, it's AngularJs problem. Can you edit/create a new question about it?